Attach resource in creation time with pivot columns
product and contracts, both has many to many relationship, I have added following in contracts nova resource.
BelongsToMany::make('Products', 'products', Products::class)
                 ->fields(function () {
                     {
                       return [
            Currency::make('Contract Price')
                ->dependsOn(['products'], function (Currency $field, NovaRequest $request, FormData $formData) {
                  $selectedProductId = $formData->products;
                  if ($selectedProductId) {
                      $product = ProductModel::find($selectedProductId);
                      $field->value = $product->price;
                  }
           }),
        ];
   }),


However, this can be attached only after contract is created. I want to check if it is possible to attach the product at the time of contract creation with ability to add the contract price which is a pivot column.
as per the answer given in following question, it does not allow me to add the pivot column value.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66359524/10535590

I am not sure I fully understand the problem you are running into.
You are trying to attach the contract to a product, and fill the pivot table with product->price. But the product can only be attached once the contract is created.
Do you want a hook that will allow a product to be auto-attached to the contract with the pivot field filled?

Apologies for the confusion, I'm trying to attach product to the contract in the create contract view, also  would like to get idea if its possible to give ability to user to put the price value as well. I can understand, with native behaviour allows the product to be attached only once the contract is created. However, we need to give this option in create contract view itself.

In you Contract model file:
// Define a property for temporary storage
protected $defaultProductId;

public function getDefaultProductId() {
    return $this->defaultProductId;
}

public function setDefaultProductId($productId) {
    $this->defaultProductId = $productId;
}

public function product(): BelongsTo {
   return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}

// hook into the saving and post save (created)
protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function ($contract) {
            $productId = $contract->attributes['product_id'] ?? false;
            unset($contract->attributes['product_id']);
            $contract->setDefaultProductId($productId);
        });

        static::created(function ($contract) {
            $productId = $contract->getDefaultProductId() ?? false;
            if ($productId) {
                $product = Product::find($productId);

                if ($product && !$product->contracts()->where('contract_id', $contract->id)->exists()) {
                    // Attach
                    $contract->products()->attach($productId, ['contract_price' => $product->price]);
                }
            }
        });
    }

In your Contract resource file:
 BelongsTo::make(__('Product'), 'product', Product::class)
                ->searchable()->showOnCreating(),

You can do the reverse if you need the relationship on Product too
